# Analyse the data of two responses while having two different scales

Tags: micro-data, comparative-statics

I am working on data analysis these days and stuck on analysis when I have to compare the two kinds of responses.
First, I have data on the self assessment, I have asked students to rate them on a scale of 1- 5 (SD-SA) on 25 behaviors, what they think about themselves.

Than though a timed exercise, I have asked assessors to access them on same behaviors on the number of occurrence and also if the student shows anything against the behavior then a negative score is also given. The scoring is done is such a way that a student can get a maximum of 4 points if they show the behaviors many times and a minimum of negative 4 if they show against.

Now, for the purpose of comparison I want to analyse both the scores. Self assessment Vs Assessor scoring, so I want to know how can I do it? I want to measure the over/under estimation of self assessment or the assessor scoring.

Should I make the assessor score into a scale too? Where -4 to -1 is disagree, -1 to 1 is neutral and 1 to 4 is Agree?
I can't seem to make it a scale of 1-5 to have a uniform score.

I have asked the same question [on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219934/analyse-the-data-of-two-responses-while-having-two-different-scales). **UPDATE: Question has been eliminated.**

Comment: Do you still have this question?